# Disable a key after functions are executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, settimeout

So basically I want the first the key ("q") to initializes the setTimeouts, then I want to **disable it from being pressed again** while the setTimeouts are running, then when the setTimeouts are over, re-allow it to be pressed again.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    // if 'q' key is pressed, initalize setTimeouts
    if (e.keyCode == 81) {
        var rock = $('#rock');

        // disable 'q' key while setTimeouts are running          
        setTimeout(function () {
            rock.css('background-position', '-34px -0px');
            setTimeout(function () {
                rock.css('background-position', '-66px -0px');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    rock.css('background-position', '-96px -0px');
                }, 300);
            }, 300);
        }, 300);
        // re enable 'q' key when setTimeouts are done      
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable before starting the timeouts, and clear it when they're done.

```
var q_enabled = true;
$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    // if 'q' key is pressed, initalize setTimeouts
    if (e.keyCode == 81 && q_enabled) {
        q_enabled = false; // Disable Q key
        var rock = $('#rock');
        setTimeout(function () {
            rock.css('background-position', '-34px -0px');
            setTimeout(function () {
                rock.css('background-position', '-66px -0px');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    rock.css('background-position', '-96px -0px')
                    q_enabled = true; // Re-enable it
                }, 300);
            }, 300);
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I can't believe I missed using booleans!